# How to reload UIViewController data from App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, icloud, appdelegate

I have some methods that I am calling from the appDelegate to sync changes with persistent storage and iCloud.

The methods and the appDelegate work fine, my app syncs changes fine; **however** when the app is `mergingChanges` and `persistentStoreDidChange` I am trying to refresh the `view controller` data and change the `view controller title` to syncing.

I have tried changing the `UIViewController` title text and it does not change when merging or `persistentStoreWillChange`, also when using the `reloadData()` method for the view controller collection the app crashes with an unexpected nil when unwrapping an optional value.

The thing is the project has many `tableview` & `colectionview` all within a `UITabController` so I really need a refresh the data of the `view controller` in the window not just one specific view. Does anybody know how to refresh the `viewcontroller` data from the `appDelegate` ?

```
func mergeChanges(notification: NSNotification) {
    NSLog("mergeChanges notif:\(notification)")
    if let moc = managedObjectContext {
        moc.performBlock {
            moc.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
            self.postRefetchDatabaseNotification()
        }
    }
    let vc = CollectionViewController()
    let view = self.window?.rootViewController

    vc.title = "Syncing"
    view?.title = "Syncing"
}

func persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.mergeChanges(notification);
}

func storesWillChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    NSLog("storesWillChange notif:\(notification)");
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        moc.performBlockAndWait {
            var error: NSError? = nil;
            if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
                NSLog("Save error: \(error)");
            } else {
                // drop any managed objects
            }

            moc.reset();
        }

       let vc = CollectionViewController()
       vc.title = "Syncing"

        // reset UI to be prepared for a totally different
        // don't load any new data yet.
    }
}

func storesDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    // here is when you can refresh your UI and
    // load new data from the new store
    let vc = CollectionViewController()
    // vc.collectionView.reloadData()

    NSLog("storesDidChange posting notif");
    self.postRefetchDatabaseNotification();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For above functionality you can use **NSNotification**  Fire that notification to multiple classes when you want to update .